# longitude and latitude format From GPS modem

Tags: google-maps, gps

for my project i need communicate with a GPS modem to get longitude and latitude.
From the device i am getting response like

```
latitude:1254.1584,N
longitude:07730.2891,E
```

but  actually for my address I found from Google-maps that co-ordinates should be

```
latitude:12.903553
longitude:77.506492
```

why am I getting different address from device? or is the address received from the device is in another format? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
N = north (positive)
E = east (positive)

latitude: DDMM.mmmm      DD = degrees 0-90,MM.mmmm minutes 0-60 
longitude: DDDMM.mmmmm  DDD = degrees 0-180,MM.mmmm minutes 0-60

12 + 54.1584/60 = 12.0.90264
077 + 30.2891/60 = 77.0.5048183
```

Comment: BRO IS THERE ANY CODE TO DO THIS?

Comment: This conversion is a variant of the DMS to DEG conversion, it is called DM to DEG. at wiki there is DMS to DEG src code.